# Method does not return after subscription - EDIT : ROS shutdowns after ros::spinOnce()

Tags: ros, spinonce

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am drawing waypoints on a map. I have a MapViewer class with the following constructor.

```
// MapViewer default constructor
MapViewer::MapViewer(std::queue<geometry_msgs::PointStamped::ConstPtr>* waypointQueue) {
  this->waypointQueue = waypointQueue;
  this->waypointColor = cv::Scalar(0,0,255);
  this->pathColor = cv::Scalar(0,255,0);
  this->mapFile = getenv("TURTLEBOT_NAVIGATION_MAP");
  this->waypointFile = getenv("TURTLEBOT_WAYPOINT_FILE");
  this->setMapMetaData();
  ROS_INFO("4");
  // TODO : Exception handling
}
```

My setMapMetaData method looks like this

```
// Get map meta data from /map_metadata topic (one time thing)
void MapViewer::setMapMetaData() {
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ROS_INFO("1");
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe(
    "/map_metadata",
    100,
    &MapViewer::mapMetaDataCb,
    this
  );
  ROS_INFO("2");
  ros::spinOnce();
  ROS_INFO("3");
  return; // I don't think this return is necessary
}
```

My subscriber callback looks like this.

```
void MapViewer::mapMetaDataCb(const nav_msgs::MapMetaData::ConstPtr& mapMetaData) {
  this->mapMetaData = *mapMetaData;
  ROS_INFO("Map metadata set");
}
```

And when I run this, my output looks like this.

```
[ INFO] [1462745271.217146294]: Initializing ROS...
[ INFO] [1462745271.221878557]: 1
[ INFO] [1462745271.228107221]: 2
[ INFO] [1462745271.228156984]: 3
```

The "Initializing ROS..." comes from the main method. The problem is even though "3" is logged, "4" never is!!!
Maybe I am missing something obvious but I have no clue as to what it is. Obviously since "3" is printed, `ros::spinOnce` must have returned. But apparently `setMapMetaData` has not returned.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing?

**EDIT**

The method actually returns. Instead of `ROS_INFO("4")`, when I use `std::cout << 4 << std::endl;` it prints 4. The issue is (as a friend explained to me) that ROS is killed when I call `spinOne()` only once and stop calling it again.

I solved the problem by changing the setMapMetaData method to

```
// Get map meta data from /map_metadata topic (one time thing)
void MapViewer::setMapMetaData() {
  ROS_INFO("Subscribing to topic %s", MapViewer::MAP_METADATA_TOPIC.c_str());
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe(
    MapViewer::MAP_METADATA_TOPIC,
    1,
    &MapViewer::mapMetaDataCb,
    this
  );
  
  while(!this->mapMetaDataSet) {
    // Block until map metadata is set
  }
}
```

And executed it in a separate thread after MapViewer instance was created.
Because I subscribe to another topic in a different class (which calls `ros::spin()` ), the `mapMetaDataCb()` is also executed at that point.

I am not accepting this as an answer because I need to figure out why ROS is killed when I don't call `spinOnce()` anymore and how to counter it. Appreciate if you could shed some light into this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233877/method-does-not-return-after-subscription---edit-:-ros-shutdowns-after-ros::spinonce()/) by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 849 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured the answer myself.
Quoting [roscpp wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown) , "When the first `ros::NodeHandle` is created it will call `ros::start()`, and when the last `ros::NodeHandle` is destroyed, it will call `ros::shutdown()`."

So in the first case, when the `setMapMetaData()` method returns, the `NodeHandler n` gets destroyed, because it's created within the scope of the method. Since there are no other NodeHandlers created at that moment, `ros::shutdown()` is called.

In the second case, the method does not return until `mapMetaDataSet = true` which happens when the callback function is executed. The callback function executes when `ros::spin()` is called from another class. Then the method returns and the local `NodeHandler n` is destroyed **BUT** now there is another NodeHandler created for the same node. Hence `ros::shutdown()` is not called at that point.

I guess my current implementation, even though it works, is not exactly the best way to get this done. Might do well to use a single NodeHandler that can be passed as an argument to subscribers / publishers etc.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-09**:
Also keep in mind that the subscriber callbacks will stop when the `ros::Subscriber` object goes out of scope and is destructed.